# Cauchy Problem: Show that if f(x)=f(−x) for all x∈R, then u(t,x)=u(t,−x) for all x∈R and t>0.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u$ is a solution to the initial-value problem (IVP) for the Heat Equation,

\begin{cases}
u_{t} - \Delta u = 0 \quad for \space (t,x) \in (0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^{d} \\
u(0,x) = f(x) \quad for \space x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \\
\end{cases}

Show that if $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, then $u(t,x) = u(t,-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $t > 0$.

...

I know that the solution to IVP is:

$u(t,x) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{4t}}f(y)dy $

My attempt in proving is as follows ( where $z = -y$ and $f(-z) = f(z)$ ):

$u(t,-x) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} f(y)e^{\frac{-|-x-y|^{2}}{4t}}dy = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} f(-z) e^{\frac{-|-x+z|^{2}}{4t}}(-dz) $

$ = -(4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} f(z)e^{\frac{-|x-z|^{2}}{4t}}dz = -u(t,x) $

So I'm close but that negative is messing up my conclusion. I'm thinking that perhaps the negative gets cancelled out somewhere or that I'm not suppose to bring it along when differentiating $z = -y$, but it's foolish if I do not. Some help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write: $u(t,-x) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} e^{\frac{-|-x-y|^{2}}{4t}}f(y)dy$.

We can make the change of variables $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $y \mapsto-y$. Notice that the inverse image of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ under this function is $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Moreover, it is injective with continuous partial derivatives and has non-zero Jacobian everywhere (in particular, $|det(D\phi(y))|=1$ $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^{d})$. We get:

$u(t,-x) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R^{d}})} e^{\frac{-|-x-\phi(y)|^{2}}{4t}}f(\phi(y))|det(D\phi(y))|dy=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} e^{\frac{-|-x+y|^{2}}{4t}}f(-y)dy$
and since $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, $f(-y)=f(y)$, we have:
$u(t,-x) = (4\pi t)^{-\frac{d}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R^{d}}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^{2}}{4t}}f(y)dy=u(t,x)$

The problem is in using the change of variables formula correctly, which is not the most trivial thing in more than one dimension.